# how to do optimum level use of snowflake cloud services 10% of free usages

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to know the tricks or best use cases to utilize the first 10% of free usage on cloud services offered by snowflake.

can we really control cloud services' billed usage?

as I can see some of my warehouses utilize very less cloud services free credits. and some of crossing the free 10% limit.

Comment: Hi - what free usage are you talking about?

Comment: I am talking about, Cloud Services Compute Costs

Costs associated with the compute used by Cloud Services. It is the compute used behind the scenes for Snowpipe, Automatic Clustering, Materialized Views and at times if you are querying the Snowflake Metadata. if your metadata queries (which are supposed to be free) are more than 10% of total compute usage then they are nominally charged by Snowflake, @NickW

Comment: If you’re asking how to use as much as possible of your “free” cloud services costs then that seems to be an odd approach - run what you need to run, don’t run additional tasks just to use up your free allowance. In any case, these costs are calculated retrospectively so you wouldn't know at the time whether a particular task would be “free” or not. If you are exceeding the 10% limit and want to reduce your costs then we would need to know what tasks you are running

Comment: got you @NickW, will collect the tasks list and update it here, but yes, I agree with what you said that this approach would be an odd one!
will collect the list of tasks and update you, Thanks